# Running command prompt insite website

Tags: javascript, command-prompt

I want to run command prompt inside the website.

Actually I want to use `Jemdoc` in my website. `Jemdoc` generates an `HTML` website if you run in command prompt the command "jemdoc index". I want that when you click a button! I dont know how to program in `PHP` or `c#`.

Can I do that in `JavaScript`?

If you could give me an example will be great (`JavaScript` or not)!!!

Comment: How badly do you want to be hacked? Opening up a direct line to the command prompt from public internet?

Comment: if you want to execute a single command you definitely want to do that on server, with [c#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25983/How-to-Execute-a-Command-in-C) or [PHP](http://chipmunkninja.com/Program-Execution-in-PHP%3A-exec-m@)

Comment: I want to execute 2 commands. One for the directory and one for the jemdoc! I try the c# code but I couldnt make it work! I think is work with one command only!!!

Comment: @sugarou: This concept will never work since it tries to break web browser security.

Comment: Can I do something else? Something different? I cant find an other way to run jemdoc!!! :(

Answer (score 0):

the Browser can not execute arbitrary commands on the clients system for very good reasons.

In short, you need a server for this! This can be PHP, Java, NodeJS or whatever. Your website sends a trigger (ie HTTP-POST) to the Server and it executes `jemdoc` (also installed on the server) for you and updates the html documents.

Greets